# Adding open and closed sets

Tags: real-analysis

My book says: let $A, B$ be subsets of $R$ if we assume $A$ is open, prove that $A+B$ is open.

Edit: thanks to the commentators, I do understand what happens when $A$ is the empty set.

Comment: If $A+B = \{a + b : a \in A \text{ and }b \in B\}$, then $A+B$ is empty if $A$ is empty, because no pairs $(a,b)$ satisfy the conditions.

Comment: Do you understand that $A+B$ is the set of all real numbers $x$ which can be written as $x=a+b$, with $a\in A$ and $b\in B$?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the set $A+b=\{a+b:a\in A\}$.  Since the map $f_b:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ given by $f_b(x)=x+b$ is continous and its inverse $f_b^{-1}(x)=x-b$ is also continuous, each $f_b$ is a homeomorphism.  So, $A+b=f_b(A)$ is open and
$$A+B=\bigcup_{b\in B}A+b.$$

Can you get it from here?

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another, more "nitty gritty" approach:

Recall that
$$A+B = \{a + b : a \in A \text{ and }b \in B\}$$

If $A$ or $B$ is empty, then there are no pairs $(a,b)$ satisfying the conditions, so $A+B$ is also empty.

So assume that $A$ and $B$ are nonempty, and $x \in A+B$. We may write $x = a+b$ with $a\in A$ and $b \in B$. As $A$ is open, there is an $\epsilon > 0$ such that the interval $(a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon)$ is contained in $A$. If $y \in (x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$, then
$$a - \epsilon< y-b <  a + \epsilon$$
so $y-b \in (a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon) \subseteq A$
and therefore $y = (y-b) + b \in A + B$. This shows that $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon) \subseteq A+B$. We conclude that $A+B$ is open.

Note that we only required one of the sets to be open.